# How span slowly stretched by 100%?

Tags: jquery

Good day.

```
<style>
.orange > span {
background-color: #e01700;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #ff4e00),color-stop(1, #e01700));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff4e00, #e01700);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff4e00, #e01700);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff4e00, #e01700);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff4e00, #e01700);
}
</style>

<div class="meter orange">
                <span style="width: 70%"></span>
           </div>
```

I would like that **span** slowly slowly stretched by 100%.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.animate`

```
$('span').animate({ width: '100%' }, 1000);
```

Comment: the second argument in .animate() is milliseconds. If "slowly slowly" means 5 seconds then use 5000